# Usercontrol not updating certain properties

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a class called MyItem that has an ID property, as well as three random number properties. I have a UserControl called MyItemControl that is designed to show a MyItem's ID, three random numbers, as well as the summation of those three random numbers. I display a collection of MyItems in a ListBox, and I have a contentcontrol that displays more detailed information about the ListBox's selected MyItem via the MyItemControl UserControl.

However, I run into a problem where, when a MyItem is selected, the contentcontrol only updates the ID and random numbers, but not the summation. My guess is because the Sum property is calculated before a MyItem is bound to the MyItemControl. I've tried raising property changed when the MyItem property is set, but that doesn't seem to work either.

How can I have the the Sum property update after the MyItem property is bound in the xaml?

MyItem Class:

```
public class MyItem
{
    private static Random random = new Random();

    public MyItem(string ID)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
        Num1 = random.Next();
        Num2 = random.Next();
        Num3 = random.Next();
    }

    public string ID { get; private set; }

    public int Num1 { get; private set; }

    public int Num2 { get; private set; }

    public int Num3 { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ID;
    }
}
```

MyItemControl xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Name="userControl" x:Class="testApp2.MyItemControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:testApp2"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel Margin="0">
        <StackPanel Margin="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="ID:" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding MyItem.ID, ElementName=userControl, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Margin="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="Num1:" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding MyItem.Num1, ElementName=userControl, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Margin="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="Num2:" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding MyItem.Num2, ElementName=userControl, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Margin="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="Num3:" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding MyItem.Num3, ElementName=userControl, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Margin="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="Sum:" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding Sum, ElementName=userControl, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

MyItemControl Code-behind:

```
public partial class MyItemControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MyItemControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }

    public MyItem MyItem
    {
        get { return (MyItem)GetValue(MyItemProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MyItemProperty, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged("MyItem");
            RaisePropertyChanged("Sum");
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyItem", typeof(MyItem), typeof(MyItemControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));


    public int Sum => MyItem != null ? MyItem.Num1 + MyItem.Num2 + MyItem.Num3 : 0;
}
```

MainWindow xaml:

```
<Window x:Name="window" x:Class="testApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:testApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Margin="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox Margin="5" SelectionChanged="ItemSelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems, ElementName=window}"/>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Selection, ElementName=window, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5">
            <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyItem}">
                    <local:MyItemControl MyItem="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow Code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        MyItems = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>
        {
            new MyItem("Boop"),
            new MyItem("Bop"),
            new MyItem("Beep")
        };
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyItems { get; private set; }

    private MyItem selection = null;
    public MyItem Selection
    {
        get { return selection; }
        set
        {
            selection = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Selection");
        }
    }

    private void ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox listbox = (ListBox)sender;
        if (listbox.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            Selection = (MyItem)listbox.SelectedItem;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you move the `Sum` property into your `MyItem` class?

Comment: @dymanoid I could. But this is just a simple example of a problem I have in a much more complicated app. I really would like to know why this problem occurs so I can fix the real problem. In my actual app, properties similar to the "sum" property needs to be updated and changed dynamically based on interactions with controls.

Comment: Two notes. 1. It is not necessary to raise a PropertyChanged event for a dependency property, hence `RaisePropertyChanged("MyItem")` is pointless. 2. You must not call anything else then SetValue in the property setter of a dependency property. The setter may not be called at all, because e.g. a Binding would directly call SetValue. So `RaisePropertyChanged("Sum")` is probably never called.

Comment: @Clemens Got it. That was kind of a shot in the dark for me. Trying to update the Sum property when the MyItem property becomes something other than null. Whenever that might occur.

Comment: It is generally odd design to have INotifyPropertyChanged implemented in a UserControl. Instead make all its properties dependency properties. If property B depends on the value of property A, update B in a PropertyChangedCallback for A.

Comment: @Clemens I looked into why that is, and it makes sense to me now. A usercontrol is already a DependencyObject so it has the tools to update its properties without the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. I tried using a PropertyChangedCallback instead, and it seems to work now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With suggestions from Clemens. I removed the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, and used a PropertyChangedCallback with the MyItem property that recalculates the Sum property. This seems to work fine.

Updated MyItemControl:

```
public partial class MyItemControl : UserControl
{
    public MyItemControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Sum = MyItem != null ? MyItem.Num1 + MyItem.Num2 + MyItem.Num3 : 0;
    }

    public MyItem MyItem
    {
        get { return (MyItem)GetValue(MyItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyItemProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyItem", typeof(MyItem), typeof(MyItemControl), new PropertyMetadata(null, MyItemPropertyChanged));

    private static void MyItemPropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyItemControl sender = (MyItemControl)obj;
        sender.Sum = sender.MyItem.Num1 + sender.MyItem.Num2 + sender.MyItem.Num3;
        Console.WriteLine("Update sum");
    }

    public int Sum
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(SumProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SumProperty, value); }
    }

    private static readonly DependencyProperty SumProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Sum", typeof(int), typeof(MyItemControl), new PropertyMetadata(0));

}
```

Comment: Small note, instead of `DependencyProperty.Register("MyItem", ...)` you could write `DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(MyItem), ...)`.